# jqgrid - trigger event for checking or unchecking rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jquery jqGrid plugin. I have used `multiselect: true` option in the config, so each row has a checkbox and I can select multiple rows in the grid. Now I want to trigger an event **when a user tries to check or uncheck each row**. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onSelectRow` event here like:

```
var lastSel;
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(id){ 
      if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
         jQuery('#gridid').restoreRow(lastSel); 
         lastSel=id; 
      } 
      jQuery('#gridid').editRow(id, true); 
   },
...
});
```

You can add your own logic inside the `onSelectRow` event. I have just given a demo example to illustrate its functionality.

As per the doc, `onSelectRow`

> Raised immediately after row was clicked. 
>   *rowid* is the id of the row,
>   *status* is the status of the selection,
>   *e* is the event object. Can be used when multiselect is set to true. true if the row is selected, false if the row is deselected.

More info here: [jqGrid events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events)